# Is there a way to pass void as an argument?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, void

I have a variadic function that calls a function for each argument.

This is what it looks like:

```
void Call()
{

}

template<typename T>
void Call(T arg)
{
    PushArg(arg);
    Call();
}

template<typename T, typename ...Args>
void Call(T arg, Args... args)
{
    PushArg(arg);
    Call(std::forward<Args...>(args)...);
}

template<typename T>
void PushArg(T arg)
{

}

template<>
void PushArg<int>(int arg)
{

}
```

If I call the function with `Call(2, 2)` it will call `PushArg<int>(2)` twice and then call `Call()`. But I need to be able to call `PushArg` but with no value.

What I want to be able to do is do `Call(2, void, 4)` and have it call `PushArg<int>(2)`, `PushArg<void>()`, then `PushArg<int>(4)`.

At the moment I have a "null" class that only exists to allow me to pass a value with no value, but it makes calling the function awkward. Is doing what I described (or something similar) possible?

Comment: No, you can't make C++ `void` fill this role. You need to use placeholder.

Comment: Where is the `arg`, used in the variadic `Call` function, defined?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Could you explain what you're asking? I had to heavily modify the original code to make it small and readable so it's possible I accidentally omitted something important.

Comment: Sorry, I see it now, and apparently the question hasn't been edited. Just ignore that, it's my eyes or visual subsystem tricking me. <DEL>Please just post **real code**. Compile it before posting it. Post it by copy and paste, not retyping.</DEL>

Comment: Regular void proposal: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0146r1.html

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't pass a type as argument of a function. The only solution I can think is a special type (your "null class", I suppose) to substitute `void`.

I think it's a clean solution, so I propose an example

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

struct voidWrp
 { };

void PushArg ()
 { std::cout << "- void PushArg" << std::endl; }

template <typename T>
void PushArg (T arg)
 { std::cout << "- generic (T) PushArg" << std::endl; }

template <>
void PushArg<int> (int arg)
 { std::cout << "- int PushArg" << std::endl; }

void Call ()
 { }

template <typename T>
void Call (T arg)
 {
   PushArg(arg);
   Call();
 }

template <typename T, typename ... Args>
void Call (T arg, Args ... args)
 {
   PushArg(arg);
   Call(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
 }

template <typename ... Args>
void Call (voidWrp const &, Args ... args)
 {
   PushArg();
   Call(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
 }

int main()
 {
   Call("std::string value", 3, voidWrp{}, 6, 7L);
 }
```

The example program prints

```
- generic (T) PushArg
- int PushArg
- void PushArg
- int PushArg
- generic (T) PushArg
```